# Calculating union of two sets of reals

Tags: inequalities, boolean-computation

Given the following two sets of reals:

```
-(1/4) < x <= 0 || 0 < x <= 1/2 || x > 1/2
x <= -1 || -1 < x < 0
```

how can I calculate their union? The expected answer is:

```
0 > x > -1/4
```

Comment: The ***union*** is all real numbers.  The ***intersection*** gives the expected answer, but it's not the only way to get the expected answer. Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try

```
Reduce[{-(1/4) < x <= 0 || 0 < x <= 1/2 || x > 1/2}, x]
```

> x > -(1/4)

```
Reduce[{x <= -1 || -1 < x < 0}, x]
```

> x < 0

```
set1 = Reduce[{-(1/4) < x <= 0 || 0 < x <= 1/2 || x > 1/2}]
set2 = Reduce[{x <= -1 || -1 < x < 0}]
Reduce[set1 && set2, x]
```

> -(1/4) < x < 0

Comment: ```In[534]:= Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{2^-x, x <= 0}, {1, x > 0}}]
Reduce@Reduce[f[x + 1] < f[2 x], x, Reals]

Out[536]= x < 0```The results not merged above come from the solution set of inequalities

Comment: Is it still nested with a layer of reduce?

Comment: See updated. Some thing like that?

Answer (score 6):

```
Simplify[(-(1/4) < x <= 0 || 0 < x <= 1/2 || x > 1/2) && (( x <= -1 || -1 < x < 0))]

(*  -(1/4) < x < 0 *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Laurenso's answer is how I'd normally do it, but let me also offer the following:

```
RegionIntersection[ImplicitRegion[-(1/4) < x <= 0 || 0 < x <= 1/2 || x > 1/2, {x}],
                   ImplicitRegion[x <= -1 || -1 < x < 0, {x}]]
   ImplicitRegion[-(1/4) < x < 0, {x}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just combine (as @Laurenso, which I have voted for)

```
w = (-(1/4) < x <= 0 || 0 < x <= 1/2 || x > 1/2) &&
   (x <= -1 || -1 < x < 0);
Reduce[w, x]
```

yields: 1/4 < x < 0

`Interval[]`: is **closed** intervals but for illustrative purposes:

```
i1 = Interval[{-1/4, 0}];
i2 = Interval[{0, 1/2}];
i3 = Interval[{1/2, Infinity}];
i4 = Interval[{-Infinity, -1}];
i5 = Interval[{-1, 0}];
i8 = IntervalIntersection[i6 = IntervalUnion[i1, i2, i3], 
   i7 = IntervalUnion[i4, i5]];
NumberLinePlot[{i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: What is differrent between '-1/4 <x<0' and -1/4<=x<=0 when I use 'NumLinePlot'?

Comment: I just wanted illustrate Interval functions. I think NumberLinePlot uses open circles for open interval  but am not near computer at present

Answer (score 4):

```
Simplify[-(1/4) < x <= 0 || 0 < x <= 1/2 || x > 1/2]
```

> `1 + 4 x > 0`